# Is $A=\{2^{-n}+1/m: n.m\in \mathbb{N}\}$ bounded? (Supremum, Infimum)

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Determine whether the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are bounded above or below. Moreover find the Supremum and Infimum (if they exist) and decide whether it is a maximum or a minimum.

Is $A=\{2^{-n}+1/m: n,m\in \mathbb{N}\}$ bounded?

Sadly, I don't know how to start with these problems. Can you please explain?

Comment: Do you mean $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean

Comment: Ok, then $1/2^n+1/m<3/2$, so A is bounded above by any $\lambda\geq3/2$. Turns out the $\sup A=3/2$ and since $1/2^n+1/m\to 0$ as $n,m\to\infty$ then $\inf A=0$. Upper/lower bound are just numbers above/below all possible numbers in the set. The infimum is the greatest lower bound (max of all possible lower bounds), and supremum is the least upper bound (min of all possible upper bounds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not?

Just observe $(\forall m):\;\frac{1}{m} \leq 1$ and $(\forall n): \frac{1}{2^n} \leq \frac{1}{2}$. Use these two to conclude the bounded ness

To make the problem easier,  write your set as $C+B$ where $C=\{\frac{1}{2^n}: n \in \Bbb N \}$ and $B=\{\frac{1}{m}: m \in \Bbb N \}$ and use $\sup (C+B)=\sup C +\sup B$ if they exist!

For infimum, use $\inf (C+B)= \inf C+ \inf B$.

Comment: If we use the definition of $\mathbb N$ in which $0\notin\mathbb N$, it may be more useful to notice $\frac{!}{2^n} \le \frac12$.

Comment: is $\sup(A)=3/2$ and $\inf(A)=0$?

Comment: Yes correct....

Comment: I believe that $\max A=3/2$ but $\min A$ does not exist